# Position list items separately

Tags: html, css, position, html-lists

Given the following HTML,

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Give me the best CSS (*without changing the HTML*) to position the elements like so:

```
Home                                                     About  Blog  Contact
```

The first list item should be left-aligned. The rest should be right-aligned.

Don't just position everything absolutely. For example, if I want to change "Blog" to "My Blog," then I shouldn't have to change the CSS for things to stay looking good.

Comment: wow... the wording of your question is kind of demanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve like below.

HTML

```
 <ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
 ul
{
 float:right;
 width:100%;    
 display:table;
}
ul li
{ 
 list-style-type:none;
 padding:0px 10px;
 background-color:#ff00ff;  
 text-align:right;
 display:table-cell;
 width:1px;
}
ul li:first-child
{
 display:table-cell;  
 float:left;
 width:auto;
}
```

[**Have a Fiddle!!**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/5XhUg/4/)

Comment: I tried this, but floating list items right reverses their order.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have fixed this issue and updated in my solution. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

This works but doesn't [ignore the whitespace between the inline-block list items](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

```
ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  width: 1024px;
}

ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul > li:first-child {
  float: left;
}

ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 21px;
}
```